# Can't run react-native run-android?

Tags: react-native

I'v followed the steps from https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. I can start the phone emulator from AVD Manager in Android Studio and I can run **react-native start** without problems. When i enter in another terminal **react-native run-android** I get the following error:

> info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can
> disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag. (node:9612) Warning: Accessing
> non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular
> dependency (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning
> was created) Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 16
> workers... info Starting JS server... info Launching emulator... info
> Successfully launched emulator. info Installing the app... Downloading
> file:/D:/App/AwesomeProject/android/gradle/wrapper/services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> D:\App\AwesomeProject\android\gradle\wrapper\services.gradle.org\distributions\gradle-6.7-all.zip
> (The system cannot find the path specified)
> at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211)
> at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:153)
> at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:108)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
> at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:189)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:78)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:63)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:68)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
> at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
> development environment set up:
> https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose
> flag for more details. Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat
> app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 Exception in thread
> "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> D:\App\AwesomeProject\android\gradle\wrapper\services.gradle.org\distributions\gradle-6.7-all.zip
> (The system cannot find the path specified)

And if I run **react-native info** I get:

> info Fetching system and libraries information... (node:14952)
> Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports
> inside circular dependency (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show
> where the warning was created) System:
> OS: Windows 10 10.0.19041
> CPU: (16) x64 AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 8-Core Processor
> Memory: 23.88 GB / 31.90 GB   Binaries:
> Node: 14.15.0 - D:\nodejs\node.EXE
> Yarn: Not Found
> npm: 6.14.8 - D:\nodejs\npm.CMD
> Watchman: Not Found   SDKs:
> Android SDK: Not Found
> Windows SDK: Not Found   IDEs:
> Android Studio: Not Found
> Visual Studio: Not Found   Languages:
> Java: 15.0.1
> Python: 3.9.0   npmPackages:
> @react-native-community/cli: ^4.13.0 => 4.13.0
> react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
> react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3
> react-native-windows: Not Found   npmGlobalPackages:
> *react-native*: Not Found

I'v tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an issue with gradle version.

Do these.

1. remove `android/.gradle` folder.
2. open `/android` in android studio
3. goto File->Project Structure->Project and change `Gradle Version` to more recent one. and wait for it to complete `gralde sync` task.
4. run `react-native run-android` after this.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I get the following error inside Android Studio in the gradle sync:                                                                                                                                  
**The specified Gradle distribution 'file:/D:/App/AwesomeProject/android/gradle/wrapper/services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip' does not exist.**